# Accepted using Vectors but Rejected using Arrays in HELP BOB problem on CODECHEF C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, bit-manipulation

reference problem https://www.codechef.com/problems/HBOB02

here in this problem i solved it using below code but firstly i used arrays instead of vector but there i got wrong answer. why so ????

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define mod 1000000007
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); 
    cin.tie(NULL);  
    cout.tie(NULL); 
    long long n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    k=k-1;
    vector<long long>arr(n); //if i use long long arr[n] here the solution is not accepted
    for(long long i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    vector<long long>ar(n); //also changing long long ar[n] here
    ar[0]=arr[0];
    for(long long i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        ar[i]=arr[i]^arr[i-1];
    }
    long long cnt=0;
    for(long long i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(ar[i]&(1<<k))
            cnt++;
    }
    cout<<cnt;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable-length arrays are not part of the C++ standard, but some compilers provide them as an extension. If they get too large, the program breaks.

However, you don't even need to store all those numbers.

Since you're apparently into "competitive" programming, here is a solution that uses only a tiny fraction of your memory, and does one third as many loop iterations.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    k -= 1;
    int cnt = 0;
    unsigned int last = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        unsigned int next;
        cin >> next;
        cnt += ((next^last) >> k) & 1;
        last = next;
    }
    cout << cnt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
in>>n>>k;

vector<long long>arr(n); //if i use long long arr[n] here the solution is not accepted
```

The size of an array variable must be a compile time constant value in C++. For obvious reasons, a value read from user input at runtime is not a compile time constant value. As such, declaring the array suggested in the comment would make the program ill-formed.